# Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a next.js project, recently when I run `npm run dev`, the above warning comes through and the project stuck and never refresh until I press ctrl + c and run npm run dev again

I deleted the repo and clone it again, deleted node-module and run npm i and deleted .next folder, but nothing work

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the warning to this post. Do you mind adding it, please?